# What does org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.Node means in jmap heap dump

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks, spring-data, jmap

I have a spring boot application that used spring data. I have native queries and query methods. Apparently i'm facing a memory issue from my application. I tried doing jmap -histo  to determine the class that uses a lot of resource.

On my first jmap dump this is the result (first day) -fresh start

[image: first]

Then on the second day this is the result

[image: second]

Notice the org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.Node starts to appear.

Then on the third day
[image: third]

The org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.Node is increasing in memory size.

Hope you can help me, or any suggestion? I haven't posted the code since I haven't isolated the one causing this. Btw, there are no operations during the night so i'm expecting garbage collection should run.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm encountering a simillar behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, hibernate is caching all of its queries this is so that hibernate will not recompile prepared statement however if you have a dynamic query it will result to memory overflow.

Ex:

Prepared Statement

```
Select * from employee where id = :id
```

-> this is okay since hibernate will just cache the prepared statement but if you do something like this

```
select * from employee where id = 1
select * from employee where id = 2
select * from employee where id = 3
```

-> Hibernate will cache that 3 statement hence the memory overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. The following configuration may help.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        query:
          plan_cache_max_size: 64
          plan_parameter_metadata_max_size: 32
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer what was causing this. However, updating the version of Spring Boot (which in turn updated the Hibernate version) to 2.2.1.RELEASE appeared to resolve these issues for me.